# Event Connections and subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, event-handling, matplotlib, color-mapping

I have what seems to be a simple task yet I am not sure how and where to start.  What I currently have is a series of subplots displayed on one figure.  Now I want to add/connect an event handler on each subplot, such that when the user clicks on one of the subplots the plot that was selected would be opened in a separate figure/window.
I want to know if this is possible and if someone could formulate a small simple code to illustrate how this can be done.
I should also mention that the only type of plot that I am using and interested in are colormaps (using `imshow()`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should read [this](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) tutorial.

Basically you need to define function which takes one arguement `event` and then attach it to your figure's canvas:

```
def open_new_figure(event):
    if event.inaxes is not None:
        ax = event.inaxes
        # you now have the axes object for that the user clicked on
        # you can use ax.children() to figure out which img artist is in this
        # axes and extract the data from it

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', open_new_figure)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Comments in your code helped me to understand how to find needed axes.